# Compiz Commands "edges actions" (screen edge bindings) not always enabled on startup.

Tags: compiz, wmctrl

When logging in, edges are sometimes unresponsive, ie right click on the edge brings the usual right click menu instead of the Compiz command. And yes, compiz is running (wmctrl -m -> Compiz).

It can be fixed with a "compiz --replace" but it's a bit frustrating.

Any idea how to fix this ? or to check Compiz logs on startup ? Known bug ?

Also, unrelated, Compiz scale plugin "on a group of window" NEVER works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Compiz to the startup applications

```
Name: Compiz
Command: bash -c "sleep 3; compiz --replace"
```

From the comment on this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/752687/comments/10

---

If you still experiment this problem, click "Affects me too" in this bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/858845

Comment: Well, for me, it doesnt happen every time, but thanks for that bug report

Answer (score 1):

Try to bind them with Ubuntu Tweak.
Ubuntu Tweak saves my edge binding settings, maybe you can try it.
See my detailed answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/150380/64580.